# Unable to create SharePoint item & update external columns content (business connectivity services)?

Tags: excel, vba, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am having trouble creating a new item within a SharePoint 2013 list. I'm able to actually create the item, though the external data (business connectivity services [bcs]) does not autopopulate as it would during the creation of the item via the SharePoint UI. Is there any way to actually make this work, or to send the function that needs to run via POST? I've pasted my current item creation sub below.

```
Dim oXMLHTTP As Object

Dim sListNameOrGuid As String
Dim sBatchXml As String
sWTF As String

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
sCurrentUser = fGetUserID

With oXMLHTTP

    .Open "POST", "MYSPSITE.COM/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('THELIST')/items", True
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
'    .setRequestHeader "X-HTTP-Method", "PATCH"
'    .setRequestHeader "If-Match", "*"
    .setRequestHeader "X-RequestDigest", fGetLoginToken



        sWTF = "{ 'User': " & Int(sCurrentUser) & ", 'newComment': 'TESTING TESTING'}"
    .send (sWTF)

    Do While .readyState <> 4:
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Debug.Print (.responseText)


    .abort

End With

Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Lower the timer job frequency.

Comment: Thank you for this, though unfortunately it will not be possible. Server side timer jobs are not adjustable from our side. I'm very curious to hear if you have any other ideas, though!